# Preciso retornar o mês anterior na query que estou montando no oracle mas está retornando o mês atual também

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tentando retornar a data de compra do mês de setembro mas me retorna também o mês de outubro. Alguém sabe como posso retornar somente o mês de setembro?
E quando for novembro retornar outubro de forma automatica (sem precisar modificar a query)
Obrigada!!!

```
       WHERE DATA_COMPRA >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)
```

Comment: O que exatamente seria "*data de compra do mês de setembro*"?

Comment: A data de compra do mês de setembro é uma coluna de data da minha tabela de compras anuais.

Comment: Não seria só trocar o `>=` por `=`?

Comment: Benilson, obrigada! Deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução que resolveria seria a seguinte:

```
WHERE DATA_COMPRA >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
AND DATA_COMPRA < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

A função TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') retorna o primeiro dia do mês atual, desta forma a cláusula WHERE está pegando todos os registros que estão entre o primeiro e o último dia do mês anterior.

Comment: Obrigada! Deu certo aqui!